# WYSIWYG Editor Alert On Submit To Find Script Tags Under HTML Formatter For CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg, onsubmit

I am trying to implement a validation check after the user tries to insert a `<script>` tag under the 'Source' (HTML) Formatter for the CKEditor.

I am doing this just for the sake of User Experience as I am aware that scripts are by default blocked by the wonderful editor.

My approach is to use Javascript/jQuery and block off the script tags on the front-end before the data is sent over as an email. However, I am unsure of why it does not work. I am attaching the relevant code.

```
  $("#sendBtn").click(function(){
        $("#messageBody").change(function(){
            if($("#messageBody").indexOf("<script>")  == 1){
                alert("No Script Tags Allowed!");
                return false;
            }   
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate any help on this issue!

Comment: *insert a 'script' tag. Stackoverflow's validation is powerful!

Comment: You should handle that at the server level, the client side (CKEditor) can be circumvented regardless of what javascript you write to handle it.  What you are suggesting for user experience sounds redundant as you say CKEditor already handles the scenario.

Comment: @Matthew, CKEditor is saving the data (even the HTML formatted data) as Rich Text, so I have absolutely no concerns about application security . However I want to ensure that no user should try sending an email with script tags multiple times before they understand that it cannot be done...I know its overkill!
Does the 'Submit' function always send the data to the server onClick?